# How-To Read Address Book (Wab) Files With C#

Tags: c#

How-To Read/Extract addresses from Outlook Address Book (Wab) Files With C#

Answer (score 1):

There's a codeplex [project](http://www.codeplex.com/Contacts) allowing you to do this.

Answer (score 1):

There is an API defined by MS:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms629361

I would like to be more specific and put some example, but i never tried it.